# Hide an activity in android

Tags: android

So I have Launcher Activity from where i can choose my equalizer activity, So I start intent and go to equalizer activity. If i want to keep my equalizer running so i cant close Activity, so  I need to hide it and go back to Launcher Activity. I tried `moveTaskToBack(true);` but it returns to Home.Is there any way to start intent(Launcher) `after moveTaskToBack(true);`

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                moveTaskToBack(true);
                return true;
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need something to run without an interface, you should implement a service instead of an activity: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html